# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a nest js app with Auth and User modules
The Auth module is written like this
It imports the User module due to the AuthService which uses it

```js
import { Module, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { GoogleStrategy } from './google.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtAuthModule } from 'src/jwt/jwt.module';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';

@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, GoogleStrategy],
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    JwtAuthModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'google' }),
  ],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

The User module is written like this

```js
import { Module, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { PrismaModule } from 'src/prisma/prisma.module';
import { JwtAuthModule } from 'src/jwt/jwt.module';
import { AuthModule } from 'src/auth/auth.module';
import { UploadModule } from 'src/upload/upload.module';

@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  imports: [
    PrismaModule,
    JwtAuthModule,
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
    UploadModule,
  ],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

It uses forwardRef to avoid circular dependency error

and the UserService is using the AuthService like this

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly prismaService: PrismaService,
  ) {}
```

Here is the App module also

```js
import { Module, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { APP_PIPE } from '@nestjs/core';
import { UploadModule } from './upload/upload.module';
import { ImageModule } from './image/image.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { PrismaModule } from './prisma/prisma.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
    UploadModule,
    ImageModule,
    PrismaModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useClass: ValidationPipe,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But it throws this error

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (?, PrismaService). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the UserModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UserModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

I tried to add services to app module and a lot of things but nothing helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Error on the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) Here is the new **UserService**

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService))
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly prismaService: PrismaService,
  ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue and moved forwardRef to AuthModule - like that `forwardRef(() => UserModule)` and it run without any problem. Please note that circular dependencies are considered bad practice. Maybe it's worth separating one more module?
Another thing is that we don't see where you import AuthService in UserService from. This may be an issue with using a separate file to group imports - [docs for reference](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

Comment: I tried to change the forwardRef from the auth to user module but it throws this error


` ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the UserModule instance.
The module at index [0] of the UserModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [0] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule]`